# Defining a 'scripts' directory in R?

Tags: r

I am working with R in several directories containing model output I'd like to analyse and plot.  I maintain a single 'scripts' directory for this project.

I'd like to be able to 'point' an environment variable at this scripts directory so that I could tab complete source(...) commands.  Is this a possibility?

So far, I've managed to create an RPATH environment variable, and have written a function in my .Rprofile which lists the directory's contents without me having to type it out.  I can't quite figure how I'd get tab completion though.

Any help/advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Cheap way I go sometimes:  `mysrc<-function(tool) source(paste0(my_directory,tool,sep='',collapse='')`

Comment: Thanks Carl, this made things a lot easier.

I guess in the future I'd consider making a package to get the autocompletion :)

Thanks to you both for the helpful responses :)